# function Return LastOrDefault()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have ExpesnseIDVM ViewModel that only contains 1 variable ExpenseID to hold the last value from the database

```
public IEnumerable<ExpesnseIDVM> Profile(LoginVM loginVM)
{
    var data = (from a in context.Employees
                where a.Email == loginVM.Email
                join b in context.Expenses on a.EmployeeId equals b.EmployeeId
                select new ExpesnseIDVM()
                { ExpenseID = b.ExpenseId }).ToList().LastOrDefault();

    return data;
}
```

I have a problem with the return type, what type of return type should I use to get the values

Comment: `public ExpesnseIDVM Profile(LoginVM loginVM)` - it is only the last one or null if there is none.

Comment: It looks like a `ExpesnseIDVM`. Hover your mouse over `data`, it will show you

Comment: And: `ToList()` is unneccessary and may have a performance penalty

Comment: As extension to Klaus & Crowcoder comments, [.LastOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=net-6.0) returns `TSource` (single).

Comment: @KlausGütter if I remember correctly then it is necessary, because entity-framework cannot translate `LastOrDefault` to sql. It is pure linq

Comment: @MongZhu Because it's not a sensible thing to do, and forcing the operation to be done is just compounding problems on top of them.  The query isn't ordered, so it makes no sense to ask for the last item of a sequence in a random order.  If the query were to be ordered, you'd reverse the sort order and get the first item to accomplish the same thing more sensibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four problems here:

- SQL Server do not guarantee order of the items if you do not specify `OrderBy`
- SQL do not have `LastOrDefault` direct translation. EF may try to reverse defined OrderBy and call `FirstOrDefault` - again `OrderBy` required
- `LastOrDefault` returns one instance, not enumerable
- `ToList()` loads whole table into the memory, but you need just one record, so do not use it.

Consider to rewrite your query in the following way:

```cs
public ExpesnseIDVM Profile(LoginVM loginVM)
{
    var data = (from a in context.Employees
                where a.Email == loginVM.Email
                join b in context.Expenses on a.EmployeeId equals b.EmployeeId
                orderby b.ExpenseId descending
                select new ExpesnseIDVM()
                { ExpenseID = b.ExpenseId }).FirstOrDefault();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: could someone explain to Bagoes how to find out the return type in future queries ?=! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have `IQueryable?<T>` as return value of the linq query, then you have `.ToList()` That makes EF to calculate the query, getting `List<T>` and finally `.LastOrDefault()` that returns single object of `T`.